# Scrape with python a website in which google log in is needed

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

First of all, I think it's worth saying that, I know there are a bunch of similar questions but none of them works for me...

I'm trying to scrape user information from a website which needs to login with google account first.

In my tests I use scraper my user settings from this page as example. The main page is 'https://www.futmondo.com' and the target page is 'http://www.futmondo.com/user/settings'

Here are what I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# TEST 1
payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'identifier': 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    'password': 'xxxxxxxxx'
}

# TEST 2
payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    'password': 'xxxxxxxxx'
}

with requests.Session() as s:

s.post('https://www.futmondo.com', data=payload)    
base_page = s.get('http://www.futmondo.com/user/settings')

soup = BeautifulSoup(base_page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
print(soup.text)
```

But I'm getting the html code without my user values.

I think that the problem is that I don't know which is the "main log in page", when I click on "Jugar" (Play) they redirect me to another page to write user ([First user web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cUnk.png),[First user html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMzae.png)), and when I write user they redirect me to another more page to write password ([Second password web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A3Aj.png),[Second password html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cw7O.png)).

Also I've searched in the html code once I've log in to find these "username" and "password" keys but I only find this: [html code once logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPava.png)
Also I've read some discussions about differences between HTTP Authentication and cookies. Still none of them worked.

Please any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: where is the login page?

Comment: What you want to scrape? Only the first name?

Comment: The login page is the main page, https://www.futmondo.com

Comment: I want to scrape several things but with an example it is ok, I can do the same for the rest.

Comment: All I need to scrape is particular for my user, then I need to do the log in first.

Comment: Please any link, documentation or idea would be appreciated.